# Not able to load a font in thymeleaf

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I use spring boot and thymeleaf for generation html.

In my resources folder, I have another folder named fonts

```
<html>
<head>
    <title th:text="${report.person.name.first}"></title>
    <style th:inline="text">
        @font-face {
            font-family: 'roboto';
            font-weight: normal;
            src:url{[[@{/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf}]]}; //issue here
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

This line don't seem ok for thymeleaf

```
src:url{[[@{/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf}]]};
```

I tried also

```
src:url{fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf};
```

But I get
Bad URL given: fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf => java.net.URISyntaxException:: missing protocol for URI: fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf

```
src:url{/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf};
```

Answer (score 0):

When using `th:inline="text"` and `[[someVariable]]` thymeleaf wil escape the slashes in the url. as such you have to use `"[(someVariable)]"` instead in those cases. this notation wil not escape characters, do not the added " as this wil also no longer be added by thymeleaf.

P.S.
It might be usefull to post what is rendered by thymeleaf using the `src:url{[[@{/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf}]]};` and what the exception is you do get when using it.

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me in a Spring Boot Thymeleaf template:

```
<style th:inline="css" type="text/css" media="screen, print">
    @font-face {
        font-family: "Roboto";
        font-weight: normal;
        src: url("[(@{/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf})]");
    }
    .test { 
        font-family: "Roboto";
    }
</style>
```

And then with a test div such as:

```
<div class="test">Test 123</div>
```

---

Notes:

1. The font file `Roboto-Regular.ttf` is in my `resources/static/fonts` folder. It is accessible (in my app) using the URL `localhost:8080/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf`. I tested this URL, to make sure the file can actually be served at the URL I want to use in my Thymeleaf template.
2. I use `<style th:inline="css"` just because this is CSS not text - although I don't think it would make a difference in this specific case.
3. You may not need any Thymeleaf at all here, given there are no Thymeleaf variables being used in the `<style>` tag. So the following works, also:

```
src: url("/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
```

4. If you were to use `[[...]]` instead of `[(...)]` then certain characters in the URL would be escaped:

```
src: url("\/fonts\/Roboto-Regular\.ttf");
```

Be careful whenever you use `[(...)]` with Thymeleaf variables containing data from untrusted sources (e.g. user inputs) since that data will *not* be escaped and could lead to security issues (e.g. running malicious code).